# Java Swing Container Won't Appear

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I'm designing a game through Java, using swing as my GUI. NetBeans is my editor, and I'm trying to use their editor mode, however whenever I run the code, nothing appears. I tried building it into a jar, but when I run the jar nothing appears still.

Here is my code:

```
package kraz;
public class KrazGUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    public KrazGUI() {
        initComponents();
        setVisible(true);
    }
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
    private void initComponents() {

        PathOptions = new javax.swing.ButtonGroup();
        InventoryOptions = new javax.swing.ButtonGroup();
        Settings = new javax.swing.ButtonGroup();
        GameOptions = new javax.swing.ButtonGroup();
        Holder = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        EventField = new javax.swing.JTextPane();
        PathLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        Left = new javax.swing.JButton();
        Right = new javax.swing.JButton();
        Middle = new javax.swing.JButton();
        InvLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        PickUp = new javax.swing.JButton();
        SetDown = new javax.swing.JButton();
        Use = new javax.swing.JButton();
        SettingLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        HighScores = new javax.swing.JButton();
        EditName = new javax.swing.JButton();
        EditGame = new javax.swing.JButton();
        ProgressLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        ProgressBar = new javax.swing.JProgressBar();
        HealthBar = new javax.swing.JProgressBar();
        HealthLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        RestartGame = new javax.swing.JButton();
        EndGame = new javax.swing.JButton();
        Exit = new javax.swing.JButton();
        GameLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        setType(java.awt.Window.Type.POPUP);

        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(EventField);

        PathLabel.setText("Path Options:");

        Left.setText("Go Left");
        PathOptions.add(Left);

        Right.setText("Go Right");
        PathOptions.add(Right);

        Middle.setText("Go Middle");
        PathOptions.add(Middle);

        InvLabel.setText("Inventory Options:");

        PickUp.setText("Pick Up");
        InventoryOptions.add(PickUp);

        SetDown.setText("Set Down");
        InventoryOptions.add(SetDown);

        Use.setText("Use");
        InventoryOptions.add(Use);

        SettingLabel.setText("Settings:");

        HighScores.setText("High Scores");
        Settings.add(HighScores);

        EditName.setText("Edit Name");
        Settings.add(EditName);

        EditGame.setText("Edit Game");
        Settings.add(EditGame);

        ProgressLabel.setText("Progress:");

        HealthLabel.setText("Health:");

        RestartGame.setText("Restart Game");
        GameOptions.add(RestartGame);

        EndGame.setText("End Game");
        GameOptions.add(EndGame);

        Exit.setText("Exit");
        GameOptions.add(Exit);

        GameLabel.setText("Game Options:");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 100, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 100, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout HolderLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(Holder);
        Holder.setLayout(HolderLayout);
        HolderLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            HolderLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(HolderLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(HolderLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(HolderLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(HolderLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                            .addGroup(HolderLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGroup(HolderLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                    .addGroup(HolderLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                                        .addComponent(InvLabel)
                                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                                        .addComponent(PickUp)
                                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                                        .addComponent(SetDown)
                                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                                        .addComponent(Use))
                                    .addGroup(HolderLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                                        .addComponent(SettingLabel)
                                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                                        .addComponent(HighScores)
                                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                                        .addComponent(EditName)
                                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                                        .addComponent(EditGame))
                                    .addGroup(HolderLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                                        .addComponent(PathLabel)
                                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                                        .addGroup(HolderLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                            .addGroup(HolderLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                                                .addComponent(Left)
                                                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                                                .addComponent(Right)
                                                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                                                .addComponent(Middle)))))
                                .addGap(0, 17, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                            .addGroup(HolderLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(ProgressLabel)
                                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                                .addComponent(ProgressBar, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 106, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                .addComponent(HealthLabel)
                                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                                .addComponent(HealthBar, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 106, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                        .addContainerGap())
                    .addGroup(HolderLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(GameLabel)
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addComponent(RestartGame)
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addComponent(EndGame)
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addComponent(Exit)
                        .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))))
        );
        HolderLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            HolderLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(HolderLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(HolderLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 103, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(HolderLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(HolderLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(Right)
                        .addComponent(Middle)
                        .addComponent(Left))
                    .addComponent(PathLabel))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(HolderLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(InvLabel)
                    .addComponent(PickUp)
                    .addComponent(SetDown)
                    .addComponent(Use))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(HolderLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(SettingLabel)
                    .addComponent(HighScores)
                    .addComponent(EditName)
                    .addComponent(EditGame))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(HolderLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addComponent(ProgressLabel)
                    .addComponent(ProgressBar, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(HealthBar, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(HealthLabel))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(HolderLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(GameLabel)
                    .addComponent(RestartGame)
                    .addComponent(EndGame)
                    .addComponent(Exit))
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(Holder, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(Holder, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new KrazGUI();
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify
    private javax.swing.JButton EditGame;
    private javax.swing.JButton EditName;
    private javax.swing.JButton EndGame;
    private javax.swing.JTextPane EventField;
    private javax.swing.JButton Exit;
    private javax.swing.JLabel GameLabel;
    private javax.swing.ButtonGroup GameOptions;
    private javax.swing.JProgressBar HealthBar;
    private javax.swing.JLabel HealthLabel;
    private javax.swing.JButton HighScores;
    private javax.swing.JPanel Holder;
    private javax.swing.JLabel InvLabel;
    private javax.swing.ButtonGroup InventoryOptions;
    private javax.swing.JButton Left;
    private javax.swing.JButton Middle;
    private javax.swing.JLabel PathLabel;
    private javax.swing.ButtonGroup PathOptions;
    private javax.swing.JButton PickUp;
    private javax.swing.JProgressBar ProgressBar;
    private javax.swing.JLabel ProgressLabel;
    private javax.swing.JButton RestartGame;
    private javax.swing.JButton Right;
    private javax.swing.JButton SetDown;
    private javax.swing.JLabel SettingLabel;
    private javax.swing.ButtonGroup Settings;
    private javax.swing.JButton Use;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    // End of variables declaration
}
```

Thanks again for the help here.

Comment: Make the shortest example showing the behavior and make it part of the question.

Comment: As Thorbjorn said, please post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: Please, learn to build the gui with code only, and do not use any tool to build the gui in Java, otherwise, you will find it difficult to maintain your code or edit it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I run this code under JDK1.6, the window shows just fine. Although, I had to comment out the following line which is JDK1.7 API

```
setType(java.awt.Window.Type.POPUP);
```

And I think that line is the problem. You made it a pop-up window. I would suggest to try with  `Type.NORMAL`.

Small side-note: you should adjust your main method to trigger the UI-code on the EDT:

```
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater( new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        new KrazGUI();
      }
    } );
  }
```

See the [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) tutorial for more information on the why.

Answer (score 2):

**I am able to execute the program in Eclipse with absolutely no probs.**
and my Java version is **version "1.7.0_03"**
[image]

**But still follows these two points below to have a better approach.**

**1.** Take out the declaration of the components from main method and put them in the Class scope, at the beginning of the class.

**2.** Place the `setVisible(true)` in the main

In the main use this...

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Test8 t = new Test8();
        t.setVisible(true);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I just pasted your code into Eclipse and it appears to be working (Java 7):

[image]

Comment: +1 for image, but see also [screenshot](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99734/how-do-i-create-a-screenshot-to-illustrate-a-post).